# Проблема с параметром cache_wsdl в PHP 5.4 в SOAP(WSDL) при соединении с 1с. Как решить?

Tags: php, 1с, soap, wsdl

Долгое время следующий код работал:

```
try{
  $client = new SoapClient("http://172.16.0.21/1c83/ws/ExchangeStorage.1cws?wsdl",
    array(
      'login' => "exchangeCRMUser",
      'password' => "password12345",
      'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
      'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
      'trace' => true,
      'features' => SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE,
      'connection_timeout' => 300,
    )
  );
}catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Выброшено исключение: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  exit;
}
```

PHP 5.4 не так давно появилась проблема через раз(иногда реже иногда чаще) появляетя ошибка: **SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://172.16.0.21/1c83/ws/ExchangeStorage.1cws?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://172.16.0.21/1c83/ws/ExchangeStorage.1cws?wsdl"** , причём проблема видимо не на стороне 1с, поскольку если ввести в браузере адрес WSDL и ввести логин с паролем, то при многократном нажатии клавиши F5 в браузере XML страница загружается без каких либо проблем. Так же удалось установить что в PHP проблемы так же не будет если закомментировать параметр **cache_wsdl**, при этом этот параметр вроде как бы нужный.

На форумах нашёл рекомендацию, через phpinfo посмотреть где папка tmp у wsdl и руками там всё удалить - сделал - не помогло.

До этого код с параметром cache_wsdl работал годами и всё было нормально. Не прошлой неделе в CRM началась проблема стали глючить контрагенты(слетали шаблоны), предположительно это происходило из за нехватки оперативной памяти - добавили, контрагенты перестали вроде бы слетать, проблема с SOAP 1с предположительно началась в то же время, хотя сейчас вопрос оперативной памяти предположительно решён(поскольку в информации на сервере отображается что теперь постоянно несколько гигобайт свободно), тем не менее проблема с SOAP 1с осталась.
В чём может быть дело?

Ещё установил на локальном ПК PHP 7.4 + soap, запустил тот же код уже раз 50 - проблемы нет.

Ещё заметил следующее: если код приведённый выше засунуть в цикл и поставить паузу между выполнениями итераций, к примеру секунду, то ошибка в рамках одного php сеанса будет или всегда появляться(при каждом соединении) или если в первой итерации проблемы не было то и в последующих итерациях ошибка не появится, хоть этих итераций 50. То есть получается что проблема именно в рамках одной инициализированной сессии PHP.